# Can you manually type moves into Arena? (copy pasting notation)

Tags: arena

Is there a way to copy/paste a game into arena? I know how to load a PGN, but suppose I have: `1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7 4. e4 d6 1-0` as my game.
Can I copy paste this anywhere to get it loaded into the GUI?

Answer (score 1):

PGN file format is a simple text format.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation

So ideally you should be able to save your text as pgn and import in GUI.

However it depends on GUI how strict the rules are for importing pgn.

For example, you can copy paste your text or import your pgn here and it works perfectly.

https://lichess.org/paste

Comment: This answer is not specific to the GUI the asker was asking about.